# How to suppress the bullet point and series name in Highmaps' tooltip?

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

When using the tooltip inside the »series« element, it displays a kind of bullet point (and eventually the series name), which I don't want to see:

[image]

Is there any way to suppress this? Couldn't find anything. Seems that this doesn't happen when using the tooltip element not within the series element. But then, I don't succeed to access the JSON country name tags.

Here [is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/9pLb8ndx/4/).

```
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {

  series: [{
    mapData: Highcharts.maps['customMap'],
    joinBy: 'ISO3CD',
    keys: ['ISO3CD', 'value'],
    data: [
      ["RUS", 200]
    ],
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{point.properties.ROMNAM}: <b>{point.value}</b>'
    }
    //data: data,
  }]
});
```

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the tooltip header which can be hidden like this:

```
tooltip: {
  headerFormat: undefined,
  pointFormat: '{point.properties.ROMNAM}: <b>{point.value}</b>'
}
```